# Intuition behind finding the H-index

Tags: java, algorithm

I found the following code snippet on [LeetCode](https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/23307/my-o-n-time-solution-use-java) that efficiently finds out the h-index of a researcher.  Wikipedia defines [h-index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-index) as "A scientist has index h if h of his/her N papers have at least h citations each, and the other N − h papers have no more than h citations each."

```
public class Solution {
    // 9.3 70 years diaoZhaTian China jiaYou 
    public int hIndex(int[] citations) {
        int length = citations.length;
        if (length == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        int[] array2 = new int[length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (citations[i] > length) {
                array2[length] += 1;
            } else {
                array2[citations[i]] += 1;
            }
        }
        int t = 0;
        int result = 0;

        for (int i = length; i >= 0; i--) {
            t = t + array2[i];
            if (t >= i) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

While I understand the purpose of the first for loop (calculating the frequencies of the various citations), what exactly is the intuition behind the second loop?  How is the index the `h-index`, when the cumulative sum (`t`) becomes greater than or equal to the index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the second loop counts down, not up - so the cumulative sum is "number of papers that have at least `i` citations"; the loop therefore finds the largest value of `i` where the number of papers is greater than the number of citations - which is exactly the definition of the h-index.

Comment: Could you kindly elaborate "_the second loop counts down, not up_"?  It starts from the length of `citations` and goes up to `0`, so in what way is it counting down (and not up)?

Comment: Usually, "counting up" refers to values that increase on each iteration (e.g. 0, 1, 2, 3), and "counting down" refers to values that decrease (e.g. 4, 3, 2, 1, 0).